# htmlagility pack and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use htmlagility pack in silverlight.  I was able to install it using the nuget package and I made a reference to it.  So far though I've only been able to get the following to mostly work

```
 document.LoadHtml(new_html)
    MessageBox.Show(document.DocumentNode.Name & "____" & document.DocumentNode.HasChildNodes) ' & "____" & document.DocumentNode.InnerText)
```

All the samples that I can find using HAP use a DocumentNode.SelectNodes which doesn't work in Silverlight.  Anyone have a simple sample using Silverlight?

Comment: Why does `SelectNodes` not work in Silverlight?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the specific Silverlight version? It's named HapLight (http://blog.j-maxx.net/#HAPLight)

Comment: SelectNodes gives me the following error...

Error 1 'selectnodes' is not a member of 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'.

Comment: Simon-I also checked out the SVN that has HAPlight. There were a few errors that I managed to fix and build it. I still have the problem with SelectNodes errors.

Comment: Anyone have anything to go on?  I dont want to have to fall back on regex

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the package.  Package was updated in Nuget for missing references